# Windows 10 synchronized with hardware clock (on system wakeup)

Tags: sync, time

I have noticed that synchronization occurs on every wake up. What is the system time? I guess, it is updated continously but why do I see the event message only on the wake up?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have windows set to sync with an internet time server, it will sync with your BIOS clock.

Read the [following link](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/08/windows-10-tutorials-154-how-to-synchronize-windows-10s-time-with-the-internet-time-server/) for help in setting windows up to automatically sync with an internet time server.